# Substract 2 Columns and show the current Value on a new one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have this DataFrame:

| Names | Account_1 | Account_2 | ID_Movement | Less_1 | Less_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_1 | 0 | 5 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_2 | 6 | 0 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_3 | 1 | 0 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_4 | 0 | 2 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_5 | 6 | 0 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_6 | 0 | 2 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_7 | 0 | 3 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_8 | 12 | 0 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_9 | 6 | 0 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_10 | 0 | 8 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_11 | 0 | 9 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_12 | 0 | 5 |

I was trying to create a new column with the current value of the account of each person with this code:

`s = (df['Account_1']).sub(df['Less_1']).groupby(df['Names']).cumsum()`
`df2['New_Account1'] = s`

Desired Output:

| Names | Account 1 | Account 2 | ID_Movement | Less_1 | Less_2 | New_Account1 | New_Account2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_1 | 0 | 11 | 35 | 59 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_2 | 6 | 0 | 29 | 59 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_3 | 6 | 0 | 23 | 59 |
| Peter | 35 | 70 | Movement_4 | 0 | 4 | 23 | 55 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_5 | 6 | 0 | 49 | 60 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_6 | 0 | 14 | 49 | 46 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_7 | 0 | 13 | 49 | 33 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_8 | 12 | 0 | 37 | 33 |
| Jhon | 55 | 60 | Movement_9 | 6 | 0 | 31 | 33 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_10 | 12 | 0 | 22 | 88 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_11 | 0 | 9 | 22 | 79 |
| William | 34 | 88 | Movement_12 | 0 | 5 | 22 | 74 |

Comment: Something like this? `df['New_Account1'] = df['Account 1'] - df['Less_1'].cumsum()`

Comment: @cornifer With this method its working for Peter, the value for the New account1 for jhon is incorrect

Comment: Note that the provided output does not match the input data

Comment: @Arancium I see, that was my mistake. I didn't do a cumsum substraction for each name separately. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and subtraction with `to_numpy()`:

```
df[['New_Account1', 'New_Account2']] = (df[['Account_1', 'Account_2']]
                                        - df.groupby('Names')[['Less_1', 'Less_2']]
                                            .cumsum().to_numpy()
                                        )
```

Output:

```
      Names  Account_1  Account_2  ID_Movement  Less_1  Less_2  New_Account1  New_Account2
0     Peter         35         70   Movement_1       0       5            35            65
1     Peter         35         70   Movement_2       6       0            29            65
2     Peter         35         70   Movement_3       1       0            28            65
3     Peter         35         70   Movement_4       0       2            28            63
4      Jhon         55         60   Movement_5       6       0            49            60
5      Jhon         55         60   Movement_6       0       2            49            58
6      Jhon         55         60   Movement_7       0       3            49            55
7      Jhon         55         60   Movement_8      12       0            37            55
8      Jhon         55         60   Movement_9       6       0            31            55
9   William         34         88  Movement_10       0       8            34            80
10  William         34         88  Movement_11       0       9            34            71
11  William         34         88  Movement_12       0       5            34            66
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lambda

```
df['New_Account1'] = df.apply(lambda row : (row['Account 1'] - row['Less_1']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: With lambda is not working, getting other values..

Comment: Names Account 1 Account 2 ID_Movement Less_1 Less_2 New_Account1
0 Peter 35 70 Movement_1 0 11 35
1 Peter 35 70 Movement_2 6 0 29
2 Peter 35 70 Movement_3 6 0 29
3 Peter 35 70 Movement_4 0 4 35
4 Jhon 55 60 Movement_5 6 0 49
5 Jhon 55 60 Movement_6 0 14 55
6 Jhon 55 60 Movement_7 0 13 55
7 Jhon 55 60 Movement_8 12 0 43
8 Jhon 55 60 Movement_9 6 0 49
9 William 34 88 Movement_10 12 0 22
10 William 34 88 Movement_11 0 9 34
11 William 34 88 Movement_12 0 5 34